# How many extensions do you have on your website?

Tags: extensions

I know Magento is made endure a lot of customization, but I'm wondering exactly how many extensions many of you guys have. We don't have a lot, probably close to 20. Just getting feelers out there.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Questions for open discussion that don't have a *correct* answer are better suited for the Magento forums over at https://community.magento.com/ or the Magento sub at https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento